# POST Image which store as a Blob with Axios - VUEJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have a data Image which store as a Blob but I dont know how to post it with Axios, I use VUEJS. Please help me.

My Object API by VueDevtool
[image]

```
<file-upload v-model="files"></file-upload>
<button type="submit" v-on:click.prevent="Submit">Submit</button>

<script>
  methods: {
    data: function () {
      return {
        config: {
          'headers': {'Authorization': 'JWT ' + this.$store.state.token},
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    },
    methods:{
      for (var file in this.files) {
        let data = new FormData()
        data.append('image', this.file[0])
        data.append('caption', 'image')
        data.append('user', this.Authuser)
        api.post('/photos/create/', data, this.config)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: @RishiRaut no. Image which store as a Blob, bro

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are almost there. The only thing you need is to append the actual file and you should pass $event to your function as: `Submit($event)`

```js
    Submit(event) {
      let URL = '....'
    
      let data = new FormData()
    
      data.append('name', 'image')
      data.append('file', event.target.files[0])
      
      let config = {
        header : {
          'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      }
    
      axios.post(URL, data, config).then(response => {
        console.log('response', response)
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log('error', error)
      })
    }
```

Comment: I got this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Ah, sorry that is supposed to be in your input, but since you are using a file upload? component then maybe use the model `this.files[0]`

Comment: If i make methods like this, it came to error: Cannot read property 'append' of undefined

Comment: Why do you need `<file-upload>` component? You can upload with it

Comment: which part of this code convert image to `blob`?

Comment: I think the content is changed into base 64 and axios posts it, but you may need to read the documentation on FormData for more on how it works