# Saving blob image in laravel's controller

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, image-uploading

In my Laravel 5/vuejs 2.6 I upload an image with the vue-upload-component and am sending a requested image blob
I try to save it with the controller code like :

```
    if ( !empty($requestData['avatar_filename']) and !empty($requestData['avatar_blob']) ) {
        $dest_image = 'public/' . Customer::getUserAvatarPath($newCustomer->id, $requestData['avatar_filename']);

        $requestData['avatar_blob']= str_replace('blob:','',$requestData['avatar_blob']);
        Storage::disk('local')->put($dest_image, file_get_contents($requestData['avatar_blob']));
        ImageOptimizer::optimize( storage_path().'/app/'.$dest_image, null );
    } // if ( !empty($page_content_image) ) {
```

As result, I have an image uploaded, but it is not readable.
The source file has 5 Kib, the resulting file has 5.8 Kib and in the browser's console I see the blobs path as

```
avatar_blob: "blob:http://local-hostels2.com/91a18493-36a7-4023-8ced-f5ea4a3c58af"
```

Have do I convert my blob to save it correctly?

**MODIFIED** :
a bit more detailed : 
In vue file  I send request using axios :

```
               let customerRegisterArray =
                    {
                        username: this.previewCustomerRegister.username,
                        email: this.previewCustomerRegister.email,
                        first_name: this.previewCustomerRegister.first_name,
                        last_name: this.previewCustomerRegister.last_name,
                        account_type: this.previewCustomerRegister.account_type,
                        phone: this.previewCustomerRegister.phone,
                        website: this.previewCustomerRegister.website,
                        notes: this.previewCustomerRegister.notes,
                        avatar_filename: this.previewCustomerRegister.avatarFile.name,
                        avatar_blob: this.previewCustomerRegister.avatarFile.blob,
                    };
                console.log("customerRegisterArray::")
                console.log(customerRegisterArray)

                axios({
                    method: ('post'),
                    url: window.API_VERSION_LINK + '/customer_register_store',
                    data: customerRegisterArray,
                }).then((response) => {
                    this.showPopupMessage("Customer Register", 'Customer added successfully ! Check entered email for activation link !', 'success');
alert( "SAVED!!::"+var_dump() )
                }).catch((error) => {
                });
```

and this.previewCustomerRegister.avatarFile.blob has value: "blob:http://local-hostels2.com/91a18493-36a7-4023-8ced-f5ea4a3c58af"
 where http://local-hostels2.com is my hosting...
 I set this value to preview image defined as :

```
            <img
                class="img-preview-wrapper"
                :src="previewCustomerRegister.avatarFile.blob"
                alt="Your avatar"
                v-show="previewCustomerRegister.avatarFile.blob"
                width="256"
                height="auto"
                id="preview_avatar_file"
            >
```

and when previewCustomerRegister.avatarFile.blob is assigned with uploaded file I see it in preview image.
I show control with saving function in first topic but when I tried to opened my generated file with kate, I found that it 
has content of my container file resources/views/index.blade.php...

What I did wrong and which is the valid way ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK #2 :**
I added 'Content-Type' in request

```
axios({
  method: ('post'),
  url: window.API_VERSION_LINK + '/customer_register_store',
  data: customerRegisterArray,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
```

but with it I got validation errors in my control, as I define control action with request:

```
public function store(CustomerRegisterRequest $request)
{
```

and in app/Http/Requests/CustomerRegisterRequest.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Traits\funcsTrait;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Customer;
class CustomerRegisterRequest extends FormRequest
{
    use funcsTrait;

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $request= Request();
        $requestData= $request->all();

        $this->debToFile(print_r( $requestData,true),'  getCustomerValidationRulesArray $requestData::');
        /* My debugging method to write data to text file 
        and with Content-Type defined above I see that $requestData is always empty
        and I got validations errors
         */

        // Validations rules 
        $customerValidationRulesArray= Customer::getCustomerValidationRulesArray( $request->get('id'), ['status'] );
        return $customerValidationRulesArray;
    }
}
```

In routes/api.php defined :

```
Route::post('customer_register_store', 'CustomerRegisterController@store');
```

In the console of my bhrowser I see : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUfhO.jpg,  https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7U56.jpg

I suppose that something is wrong in axios header ? without 'Content-Type' defined my validation rules work ok...

**MODIFIED BLOCK #3**

I managed to make fetch of blob with metod like :

```
            var self = this;

            fetch(this.previewCustomerRegister.avatarFile.blob) .then(function(response) {
                console.log("fetch response::")
                console.log( response )

                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.blob().then(function(myBlob) {
                        var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
                        // myImage.src = objectURL;
                        console.log("objectURL::")
                        console.log( objectURL )

                        console.log("self::")
                        console.log( self )



                        let customerRegisterArray =
                            {
                                username: self.previewCustomerRegister.username,
                                email: self.previewCustomerRegister.email,
                                first_name: self.previewCustomerRegister.first_name,
                                last_name: self.previewCustomerRegister.last_name,
                                account_type: self.previewCustomerRegister.account_type,
                                phone: self.previewCustomerRegister.phone,
                                website: self.previewCustomerRegister.website,
                                notes: self.previewCustomerRegister.notes,
                                avatar_filename: self.previewCustomerRegister.avatarFile.name,
                                avatar: objectURL,
                            };

                        console.log("customerRegisterArray::")
                        console.log(customerRegisterArray)

                        axios({
                            method: 'POST',
                            url: window.API_VERSION_LINK + '/customer_register_store',
                            data: customerRegisterArray,
                            // headers: {
                            //     'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'  // multipart/form-data - as we need to upload with image
                            // }
                        }).then((response) => {
                            self.is_page_updating = false
                            self.message = ''
                            self.showPopupMessage("Customer Register", 'Customer added successfully ! Check entered email for activation link !', 'success');
                            alert( "SAVED!!::")
                        }).catch((error) => {







  self.$setLaravelValidationErrorsFromResponse(error.response.data);
                            self.is_page_updating = false
                            self.showRunTimeError(error, this);
                            self.showPopupMessage("Customer Register", 'Error adding customer ! Check Details fields !', 'warn');
                            // window.grecaptcha.reset()
                            self.is_recaptcha_verified = false;
                            self.$refs.customer_register_wizard.changeTab(3,0)
                        });


                    });
                } else {
                    return response.json().then(function(jsonError) {
                        // ...
                    });
                }
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ', error.message);
            });
```

In objectURL and self I see proper values : https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQDuX.jpg

1) But checking data on server in laravel's control I see the same values I had at start of my attemps to upload image:

[avatar_filename] => patlongred.jpg
[avatar] => blob:http://local-hostels2.com/d9bf4b66-42b9-4990-9325-a72dc8c3a392

Have To manipulate with fetched bnlob in some other way ?

2) If I set :

```
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
```

I got validation errors that my data were not correctly requested...

?

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED

Comment: I still search for decision.
Who use vue-upload-component component files uploading in vuejs with laravel in control ?
How do you save blob image uploaded with vue-upload-component component?
Please, share working example...

Comment: This is a dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809402/post-image-which-store-as-a-blob-with-axios-vuejs

Comment: Do you really need to paste that much codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using request type as `application/json` hence you won't be able to save the image this way, for a file upload a request type should be `multipart/form-data` in this case you'll need to send request as

```
let customerRegisterArray = new FormData();
customerRegisterArray.put('username', this.previewCustomerRegister.username);
customerRegisterArray.put('email', this.previewCustomerRegister.email);
....
customerRegisterArray.put('avatar', this.previewCustomerRegister.avatarFile);

console.log("customerRegisterArray::")
console.log(customerRegisterArray)

axios({
  method: ('post'),
  url: window.API_VERSION_LINK + '/customer_register_store',
  data: customerRegisterArray,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
}).then((response) => {
     this.showPopupMessage("Customer Register", 'Customer added successfully !Check entered email for activation link !', 'success');
     alert( "SAVED!!::"+var_dump() )
}).catch((error) => {});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Please look at MODIFIED BLOCK #2

Comment: as per your `MODIFIED BLOCK #2` you're sending request as https://imgur.com/a/wJEbBnP which is still wrong, you cannot send a JSON object in request with  'multipart/form-data', also you can't send Blob URL to upload file, you need to send File uploaded,

for more details you can refer to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/22087178/11950301

Comment: as I use vue-upload-component and it keeps url of blob(I made preview of this uploaded file on my form)
that seems tricky how can I to convurt blob into File uploaded ?

Comment: you can probably do `fetch(blobUrl).then(res => res.blob()).catch(err => { //handle err })`

Comment: Thank you for your help!
Please look at MODIFIED BLOCK #3

Comment: but you are not sending request correctly yet, it will always throw error this way. You cant sent http request with `multipart/form-data` using `JSON` you should use `new FormData();` to create a form object and then send the request

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your help!

Valid decision was :

```
        var self = this;

        fetch(this.previewCustomerRegister.avatarFile.blob) .then(function(response) {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.blob().then(function(myBlob) {

                    var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);

                    let data = new FormData()
                    data.append('username', self.previewCustomerRegister.username)
                    data.append('email', self.previewCustomerRegister.email)
                    data.append('first_name', self.previewCustomerRegister.first_name)
                    data.append('last_name', self.previewCustomerRegister.last_name)
                    data.append('account_type', self.previewCustomerRegister.account_type)
                    data.append('phone', self.previewCustomerRegister.phone)
                    data.append('website', self.previewCustomerRegister.website)
                    data.append('notes', self.previewCustomerRegister.notes)
                    data.append('avatar_filename', self.previewCustomerRegister.avatarFile.name)
                    data.append('avatar', myBlob)

                    axios({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: window.API_VERSION_LINK + '/customer_register_store',
                        data: data,
                        headers: {
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'  // multipart/form-data - as we need to upload with image
                        }
                    }).then((response) => {
                        self.is_page_updating = false
                        self.message = ''
                        self.showPopupMessage("Customer Register", 'Customer added successfully ! Check entered email for activation link !', 'success');
                        alert( "SAVED!!::123")
                        // self.$router.push({path: '/'});
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        self.$setLaravelValidationErrorsFromResponse(error.response.data);
                        self.is_page_updating = false

                        self.showRunTimeError(error, this);
                        self.showPopupMessage("Customer Register", 'Error adding customer ! Check Details fields !', 'warn');
                        window.grecaptcha.reset()
                        self.is_recaptcha_verified = false;
                        self.$refs.customer_register_wizard.changeTab(3,0)
                    });


                });
            } else {
                return response.json().then(function(jsonError) {
                    // ...
                });
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ', error.message);
        });
```

and common laravel's file uploading functionality :

```
$customerAvatarUploadedFile = $request->file('avatar');
...
```