# How to Receive Blob Object from Axios in Express.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios

I'm developing an API that sends a Blob Object created in Vue.js to Express.js via Axios.post.

**Vue.js**

```
...
const blobObject = new Blob([content]);

axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/post`, blobObject)
    .then(
         (response) => {
              console.log('Successfully Save API')
          },
          (err) => {
              console.error(err)
          }
    )
```

However, Blob Object appears through req.body, but undefined is output through req.body.blobObject.

**Express.js**
...

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const { blobObject } = req.body;
    console.log(blobObject) // undefined

    console.log(req.body) // Blob Object OK
    // req.body
    // [Object: null prototype] { ...String in Blob Object... }
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please, provide full data of req.body

Comment: @cccn 
I modified the data I send to Axios and commented the data output through req.body.

Comment: `req.body` is an object and you send only blob without object. So, there is no `blobObject` property inside `req.body` object.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const blobObject = new Blob([content])
const data = new FormData()
data.append('file', blobObject)

axios.post('http://localhost:3000/post', data)
```

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809402/post-image-which-store-as-a-blob-with-axios-vuejs).

Comment: router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const { file} = req.body;


   
}

Comment: Still in Express, req.body.data is undefined.